# Migrating to AWS SDK v3 NextJs aws-ses Simple Email Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-nodejs

I would like to migrate my ses-utils typescript function based on aws sdk v2 to v3

Here is my code:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import { SES, SESClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
require('dotenv').config();

AWS.config.update({
  region: `${process.env.AWS_REGION}`,
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
})

const ses = new SES({ apiVersion: 'latest' });

interface EmailParams {
  Source: string;
  Destination: {
    ToAddresses: string[];
  };
  Message: {
    Subject: { Data: string };
    Body: { Html: { Data: string } };
  };
}

const sendEmail = async (params: EmailParams): Promise<void> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ses.sendEmail(params, (err:any, data:any) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
};

export { sendEmail };
```

I've tried with the automated migrating tool suggested by AWS but it doesn't work properly in my case. It just added to my code the following line:

```
import { SES, SESClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
```

Could someone help me migrating this code to version 3 of AWS SDK?

Comment: I've resolved my problem! In my case the solution was [linked here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/ses/src/ses_sendemail.js).

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem was [linked here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/ses/src/ses_sendemail.js).

In particular, I've edited my ses-utils.ts with these following lines of code:

```
import { SendEmailCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
import { sesClient } from "./sesClient.js";

interface EmailParams {
  Source: string;
  Destination: {
    ToAddresses: string[];
  };
  Message: {
    Subject: { Data: string };
    Body: { Html: { Data: string } };
  };
}

const sendEmail = async (params: EmailParams): Promise<void> => { 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sesClient.send(new SendEmailCommand (params), (err:any, data:any) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  });
};

export {sendEmail};
```

I've used a sesClient.js component as follows:

```
/* Copyright Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
ABOUT THIS NODE.JS EXAMPLE: This example works with the AWS SDK for JavaScript version 3 (v3),
which is available at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3. This example is in the 'AWS SDK for JavaScript v3 Developer Guide' at
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/ses-examples.html.

Purpose:
sesClient.js is a helper function that creates an Amazon Simple Email Services (Amazon SES) service client.

*/
// snippet-start:[ses.JavaScript.createclientv3]
import { SESClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-ses";
// Set the AWS Region.
const REGION = "region-aws-1";
// Create SES service object.
const sesClient = new SESClient({ region: REGION });
export { sesClient };
// snippet-end:[ses.JavaScript.createclientv3]
```

Hope you will find this answer useful